# Angular 2 router component not init until interaction

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

When a route is loaded all the static content of its template is rendered. But all the elements that have bindings are hidden until the first interaction is made.

After reducing the project to the simplest I have this:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages/';

@Component({
    selector: 'admin-app',
    templateUrl: 'admin.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '/pages', name: 'Pages', component: PagesComponent },
])
export class AdminAppComponent {
    test = 'Binding from main component';
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<p>
  {{test}}
</p>
<a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
<a [routerLink]="['Pages']">Pages</a>
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

**pages.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'go-pages',
    templateUrl: 'pages.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['pages.component.css']
})
export class PagesComponent {
    test = 'YES';
    constructor() { }
}
```

**pages.component.html**

```html
<p>
  pages works!
</p>
<p>
  Bindings work -> {{test}}
</p>
```

If I go to http://localhost:4200/pages in the browser, the following things happen:

- The `<p>{{test}}</p>` is allways rendered, as 'Binding from main component'
- The `<p>pages works!</p>` renders always too.
- The `<p>Bindings work -> {{test}}</p>` sometimes is rendered on start, but most of the times i have to click again at `<a>Pages</a>`, and then it always appears

I'm using angular and router-deprecated 2.0.0-rc.1.

Comment: How to you provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`?

Comment: At bootstrap: `bootstrap(AdminAppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS])`

Comment: Can you reproduce in Chrome or only other browsers?

Comment: It happens at Chrome, Firefox and IE all of them with the last version

Comment: No idea. I see this issue mentioned the first time. I'd suggest to the new router instead wasting more time on the deprecated router anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway, I'll try to migrate to the new router :)

Comment: I guess there will be a new release tomorrow and then most issues should be fixed. It's working quite well already.